# Angular - access ng-template outside my host component

Tags: angular

How can i access templates that are not part of my host component without passing them as input?

being more specific i would like to do something like this:

```
@ViewChildren(ToolbarCustomTemplateDirective, {read: TemplateRef}) templates: QueryList<TemplateRef<any>>;
```

just without the ViewChildren

Answer (score 0):

If your parent component has this:

```
<toolbar>
  <ng-template toolbarCustomTemplate>
    template 1
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template toolbarCustomTemplate>
    template 2
  </ng-template>
</toolbar>
```

You can access it in your toolbar component using [`ContentChildren`](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren)

```
@ContentChildren(ToolbarCustomTemplateDirective, {read: TemplateRef})
templates?: QueryList<TemplateRef<any>>;
```

Comment: Well my toolbar is constant in every page, but he is changing his content according to the page, the templates are need to be inside the page component.

Comment: @YochaiAkoka you would need to provide more code, and explanation about your structure. However, if it's enough, you can listen for  QueryList changes using the `templates.changes` Observable on the ContentChildren property result